# How can I make my agent to ask for missing tool parameters and get them in a specific format

Tags: langchain

I plan to use multiple tools.
I want multiple mandatory tool params and some optional params for creating an appointment

- begin iso8601
- topic
  ...

I use AgentType.STRUCTURED_CHAT_ZERO_SHOT_REACT_DESCRIPTION

When a user just says "I want an appointment" ... like on any other tool I want the LLM to ask the user for missing required params. like "When do you want the appointment"

On "I want an appointment tomorrow ..." to get an iso8601 date instead of a string "tomorrorow". Is there an example how this would work in the tool description?